# Unable to change class attribute

Tags: python

class GameState:

```
def __init__(self):
    '''initializes the players turn'''
    self._player_turn = 'BLACK'

board = []
def create_board2(self):
    '''creates the board with the given number of rows and columns'''
    new_game = GameState()
    rows = []
    columns = []
    r = int(new_game.num_rows())
    c = int(new_game.num_columns())
    columns = [None] *c
    for row in range(c):
        columns[row] = ['.'] * r
    middle = len(columns) // 2
    columns[middle - 1][middle - 1] = 'B'
    columns[middle - 1][middle] = 'W'
    columns[middle][middle - 1] = 'W'
    columns[middle][middle] = 'B'
    new_board = self.board.append(columns)
    print(new_board)
    return new_board
```

it prints out none. I am trying to create a class attribute which is a list. I need to use it for various functions.

Comment: Can you please format your code; and also append your question with regards to what your task is, what you are having a problem with, and most importantly a question that can be answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method returns `None` because you are returning the return value of your `append` call; which is `None`. You can discover this behavior with:

```
print(type([].append(1)))
```

I think what you want to do is return `self.board`, or assign `self.board` to `new_board` on a separate line.